# How to auto increment a field

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a column of values that are a combination of the letter `S` and a series of incrementing numbers.

How can I auto increment the sequence of numbers for each row instead of doing it manually?

For example:

```
S1
S2
S3
S4
. 
. 
. 
Sn
```

Answer (score 17):

One way would be to provide the first two items, then mark both and drag at the lower right corner for as many rows as you like:

[image: Dragging lower right corner]

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use a formula that concatenates `S` with the current row number:

```
="S"& Row()
```

If your numbering does not start in Row 1, you can offset the row number in the formula.

For example, if you wish to start with `S1` in Row 8, `S2` in Row 9, and so forth, your adjusted formula would be:

```
="S"& row()-7
```

You could also use a single array formula to number multiple rows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("S"& row(A1:A20))
```

Offset Version:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("S"& row(A8:A27)-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Automatically create a series or list

Source: [Use autofill to complete a series (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58173?hl=en)

1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. In a column or row, enter text, numbers, or dates in at least two cells next to each other.
3. Highlight the cells. You’ll see a small blue box in the lower right corner.
4. Drag the blue box any number of cells down or across.

   - If the cells form a series of dates or numbers, the series will continue across the selected cells.
   - If the cells don’t form a series of dates or numbers, the list of values will repeat across the selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Say your column with values is "O" then the formula to generate ids can be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(O3:O) ,,"S"&ROW(O3:O)))
```

Comment: This answer does not appear to be to the question asked by OP. There is no requirement to skip rows.

Answer (score 0):

## SEQUENCE

This function is used to create a sequence of numbers.  For example if you want to create a sequence from 1 to 20:

```
=SEQUENCE(20)
```

You can prepend `S` onto it using ARRAYFORMULA

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("S" & SEQUENCE(20))
```

You can also create it dynamically from the current row up to the last row that contains a value.

For example, if your values are in Column B:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("S"& 
   SEQUENCE(
     MAX(FILTER(
       ROW(B:B),LEN(B:B)))-ROW()+1))
```